# horizontal drop down menus in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, drop-down-menu

I am revisiting the first site I ever built to deal with some issues. I'm not a pro web developer as I have basically taught myself everything I know.

The website http://www.watermarkliving.ca/ has a horizontal drop down menu at the top which when the mouse is hovered over, produces a drop down sub menu with a transparent png background.

My problem is that this menu does not function in **IE 6** and in **IE 7** it functions improperly in that the sub menu drops down below the main menu item next to it.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to fix this and I believe it is simply an issue of CSS. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `left:0` to the drop down menu, what it does is calculates the width of the parent LI then applies that to the left position of the child UL, when you don't have a "left" attribute applied in the CSS.

Comment: That does indeed fix IE7. You were about a minute faster than me :(

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much... That fixed IE7 like a charm. Now for the real pain in the but.... Anyone know how to make it function in IE6?

Comment: A similar menu not working in IE7 but works in chrome. Left:-9999px is mentioned already on the dropping div. if i change it to left:0, still its messing with chrome and not working in ie. whatta do now ?